# Write the Radon-Nikodym derivative on a subset $Y$ as a sum of the derivative over the entire space

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, ergodic-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $f:X \to X$ a locally invertible non-singular* map of the Lebesgue space[[1]](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lebesgue_space) $(X,\mathcal{B},m)$ and a partition $\{X_i\}$ of $X$ with $m(X_i)<\infty$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\bigcup f^{-n}(X_i)$ which is complete with respect to $m$.

Define

$$(m\circ f)(A):=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}m(f(A \cap X_i)).$$

We have that $m\ll m\circ f$ so let $g=\frac{dm}{dm\circ f}$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Let $Y\subset X$ be a measurable subset, we can restrict the map and the measures in this subspace, so that $g_{Y}=\frac{dm_Y}{dm_Y \circ f|_Y}$.

Now I need to show the identity,

$$\log{g_Y}=\sum_{i=0}^{\tau_Y-1}{\log{g\circ f^i}}\tag{1}\label{eq}$$

where $\tau_Y=\inf{\{n\ge1:f^n \in Y\}}$ is the first return time.

---

> A measurable map $f:X\rightarrow X$ on a measure space $(X,\mathcal{B},m)$ is nonsingular if $m(f^{-1}(A))=0$ for all $A\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $m(A) = 0$

My first attempt was to work "*backwards*" so that I could see how to get to $\eqref{eq}$, but I only managed to reach the expression
$$g_Y = \prod_{i=0}^{\tau_Y-1}g\circ f^i.$$

This expression is very similar to an exercise in Viana's book, [Foundations of Ergodic Theory](https://www.usb.ac.ir/FileStaff/1227_2019-9-30-7-55-41.pdf). [Exercise 9.7.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDE7t.png), but I couldn't solve it.

I believe that by the uniqueness of the Radon–Nikodym derivative, in $Y$ we have to have the equality $g = g_Y$, but I don't know how this can be useful to me.

Does anyone have any idea how to find this equality? And is she known? It seems to me that yes, it is very similar to the definition of entropy....

Comment: 1. $(X,m)$ is an abstract $\sigma$-finite measure space. What do you mean by "$m$ being the Lebesgue measure"?   The Lebesgue measure is typically defined in the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra in $\Bbb R^n$.

2. In general, the image of a measurable set by a measurable function may not to be measurable. So, $m(f(A \cap X_i))$ may not be defined.

3. Suppose $X= \Bbb R$, $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is the constant function $f(x)=0$.  Then $m \circ f$ is identically zero.  And, it is not true that $m\ll m\circ f$.

Comment: @Ramiro You're right, I was assuming "where things make sense", but it really is necessary to make things more explicit. I believe it is now correct.

Comment: @Mrcrg Could you please add the source of your question?

Comment: Up to some typos possibly, this essentially follows from the chain rule for the Radon-Nikodym derivatives.

Comment: @AlpUzman It was at a lecture, where it was said "it's easy to see $\eqref{eq}$". Actually $g$ is going to be the jacobian and in this case, I think what I wrote in the question was adapting the mentioned exercise to countable Markov shifts.
I'll try to use the chain rule (but I always end up getting lost). Thanks!